# Running all combinations of tests and test cases in Haskell

Tags: haskell, testing

I aim to be able to define a collection of test methods and a collection of test cases (input/output data) and then execute all of their combinations. The goal is to avoid re-writing the same code over and over again when having say, 3 different implementations of the same function and 4 test cases that the function should satisfy. A naive approach would require me to write 12 lines of code:

testMethod1 testCase1

testMethod1 testCase2

...

testMethod3 testCase4

I've a gut feeling that Haskell should provide a way to abstract this pattern somehow. The best thing I've currently came up with is this piece of code:

```
import Control.Applicative

data TestMethod a = TM a
data TestData inp res = TD inp res

runMetod (TM m) (TD x res) = m x == res

runAllMethods ((m, inp):xs) = show (runMetod m inp) ++ "\n" ++ runAllMethods xs
runAllMethods _          = ""

head1 = head
head2 (x:xs) = x
testMethods = [TM head1, TM head2]
testData = [TD [1,2,3] 1, TD [4,5,6] 4]

combos = (,) <$> testMethods <*> testData

main = putStrLn $ runAllMethods combos
```

This works, computes 2 tests against two 2 functions and prints out 4 successes:

```
True
True
True
True
```

However, this works only for lists of the same type, even though the head function is list type agnostic. I would like to have a test data collection of any lists, like so:

```
import Control.Applicative

data TestMethod a = TM a
data TestData inp res = TD inp res

runMetod (TM m) (TD x res) = m x == res

runAllMethods ((m, inp):xs) = show (runMetod m inp) ++ "\n" ++ runAllMethods xs
runAllMethods _          = ""

head1 = head
head2 (x:xs) = x
testMethods = [TM head1, TM head2]
testData = [TD [1,2,3] 1, TD ['a','b','c'] 'a']

combos = (,) <$> testMethods <*> testData

main = putStrLn $ runAllMethods combos
```

but this fails with an error:

```
main.hs:12:21: error:
No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘1’
In the expression: 1
In the first argument of ‘TD’, namely ‘[1, 2, 3]’
In the expression: TD [1, 2, 3] 1
```

Is it possible to achieve this test-function X test-case cross testing somehow?

Comment: It seems like you should probably switch to something like [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.10.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) or [HUnit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.6.0.0/docs/Test-HUnit-Base.html) (or a combining framework like [Tasty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-1.0.0.1)).

Comment: In the specific case of the `head :: [a]->a` function, note that it is enough to test it on integers. Indeed, if it works on integers, by the free theorem associated to its polymorphic type, it has to work on all other types. Here, parametricity lets us avoid testing on infinitely many types. This often happens on list-related functions.

Comment: Downvoters: please leave a comment. In my view, this question describes the issue pretty well, and shows research effort. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use QuickCheck or similar, like hnefatl said.
But just for the fun of it, let's get your idea to work.

So you have a polymorphic function and a lot of test cases of different types. The only thing that matters is that you can apply the function each of the types.

So let's have a look at your function. It's of type `[a] -> a`. How should your test data look like? It should consist of a list, of a value, and it should support equality comparison. That leads you to a definition like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data TestData where
  TestData :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> TestData
```

You need to enable the `GADTs` language extension for this to work. For the following to work, you need these other two extensions (although the whole thing can be generalised with type classes to avoid that, just look at QuickCheck).

Now test it:

```
head1 = head
head2 (a : as) = a

test :: (forall a . [a] -> a) -> TestData -> Bool
test f (TestData as a) = f as == a

testAll :: [(forall a . [a] -> a)] -> [TestData] -> Bool
testAll fs testDatas = and $ test <$> fs <*> testDatas

main = putStrLn $ if testAll [head1, head2] [TestData "Foo" 'F', TestData [1..] 1]
  then "Success!"
  else "Oh noez!"
```

I'll leave it to you to generalise this for different test function types.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I failed to get it to work. The compiler complains that: Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘a’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          TestData :: forall a. Eq a => [a] -> a -> TestData,
        in an equation for ‘test’
I assume this is because TestData does not carry any info about what types it actually contains and then the compiler assumes that the a's in function test :: ([a] -> a) -> TestData -> Bool could be different from the ones in it's TestData input parameter.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys, that'll teach me to upload code without compiling it beforehand. See the updated code.

Comment: Thanks! This is a cool solution all in all. But how (or if) does the (forall a . [a] -> a) relate to TestData?

Comment: @PetrasPurlys, `forall a . [a] -> a` is the type of `head`.

Comment: It's not enough to change the [a] to b to get the generalized version, is it? I'd appreciate some hints, it might be too hard for me to do this on my own.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys, no, since there are no (sensible) functions `b -> a`. From here, you need to decide in which direction you want to go. You could generalise lists to arbitrary type operators `t a` and carry `t` as a parameter, i.e. `TestData t`. But in practice, you should really do the QuickCheck tutorial ;)